# Is there any method to stop python program from crashing?

Tags: python, windows, jupyter-notebook, crash

Below is a normal program in which I am trying to take odd index numbers from listOne and even index number from listTwo and then appending those numbers in listThree, but every tome I run it in a jupyter notebook my laptop freezes and I have to force shutdown it, please help me to understand what is wrong with the code, why it crashes every time??

```
listOne=[3,6,9,12,15,18,21]
listTwo=[4,8,12,16,20,24,28]
listThree=[]
[listThree.append(i) for i in listOne if i%2!=0]
[listTwo.append(i) for i in listTwo if i%2==0]
print(listThree)
```

Answer (score 1):

using append in a list comprehension is wrong and ultimately defeats the purpose of even using one...

```
print([i for x,i in enumerate(listOne) if x%2 == 1] + [i for x,i in enumerate(listTwo) if x%2 == 0])
```

```
[6, 12, 18, 4, 12, 20, 28]
```

Comment: From the problem description I think everything is supposed to end up in `ListThree`, not that makes this in anyway bad advice.

Comment: Thankyou @Ironkey I am new to this language, I am just making myself comfortable with this language at very basic level.

Comment: Talking about question it is to take odd index number's from listOne [6,12,18] and even index number from listTwo [4,12,20,28], now to merge it in new list namely listThree. So, finalresult will be listThree=[6,12,18,4,12,20,28]

Answer (score 0):

So here is the clear solution of above question:

```
listOne=[3,6,9,12,15,18,21]
listTwo=[4,8,12,16,20,24,28]
listThree=[]
for i in listOne:
    if listOne.index(i)%2!=0:
        listThree.append(i)
for i in listTwo:
    if listTwo.index(i)%2==0:
        listThree.append(i)
print(listThree)
```

```
[6, 12, 18, 4, 12, 20, 28]
```

Comment: using index is not really the best way to do that, see my updated answer for using `enumerate`

Comment: Thanks once again bro, but I hope what I did is not wrong but lengthy, right?

Comment: no its not wrong! `list.index()` is just a little cumbersome and that's why we have `enumerate` built-in so you don't have to use it as much :)